# AMD Radeon R5 M330 is not listed in Blender Preferences

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, gpu

my AMD Radeon R5 M330 GPU is not listed in the Blender preferences. I'm using windows 10, intel core i3, 8GB RAM, 2.0 GHz Processor, and 2GB Graphics Card(AMD).
And I'm using Blender 2.81a.[image: screenshotOfBlender]

[image: GPU_device]

Comment: Hi, could you reformulate so we know what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Also, the **exact** driver version would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

After a quick search I found this:

OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Your GPU is GCN 1st generation. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_R5/R7/R9_M300_series

Answer (score 0):

Blender dropped support for GCN 1.0 GPUs in 2.79

If you want to use your GPU you will have to use 2.78 or earlier versions.